# PHP json_decode for key with non-alphanumeric character

Tags: php, json

Suppose your JSON data has a key like "@id" ... with a non-alphanum character... How do you reference it via php json_decode?

->"@id" and ->'@id' don't seem to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as always.

```
$decoded_json->{'@id'}
```