# How to get the property of an object which has a dash (-) in between name

Tags: php

I have an object which has a property called "Employee-ID";

Im trying to get its value by:

```
echo ($row->Employee-ID);
```

But PHP keeps saying:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$Employee
 Use of undefined constant ID - assumed 'ID'
```

I just have the problem with this propert which has "-" in between; how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Use underscores, or use caps.
Employee_ID or EmployeeID

Comment: `$row->{'Employee-ID'}` might work.

Comment: @AlexandreTryHardLeblanc: Doesn't help if the object has been created by e.g. parsing XML.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18116433 http://stackoverflow.com/q/13078453 http://stackoverflow.com/q/9864068 http://stackoverflow.com/q/12522199 http://stackoverflow.com/q/10810028

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same as always.

```
$row->{'Employee-ID'}
```